# SSIS Row Count Variable information in a Email Script Task

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, ssis, msbi

I am trying to get the Row count variable information which is there in a Data flow task to the Script task in the same package with no luck.

I have given the row count as an integer and declared at the package level so that i can call in the Script task but there is an error throwing when declaring the variable, below is the example

dts.variable("rownumercount").value

i also tried to convert this to string,

dim ncr as string = convert.tostring(dts.variable("rownumercount").value)

can any one please help, as i'm trying this to get the number if inserted records in a automatic email.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of possible flaws in your example:

1. Variables are only available in your script when they are added to the `ReadOnlyVariables` or `ReadWriteVariables` properties of the Script Task.
2. The collection containing variables is called `Variables`, not `Variable`. Meaning that the correct syntax is `Dts.Variables("name_of_the_variable")` in VB.NET.
3. Check your spelling. Is your variable really called `rownumercount`, or is it actually the correctly spelled `rownumBercount`.
4. User variables are normally prefixed with `User::`. Try the following syntax: `Dts.Variables("User::rownumbercount").Value`.